# Ubuntu java error logging

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Is there a way on Ubuntu to enable global java exception logging? In my case I have php-fpm executing java jar with php function `exec()`, but I don't get any exceptions logged from Java anywhere.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and my Java version is

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Depends what kind of logging you are expecting. Are you logging to standard output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't understand what do you mean by "standard output"?

Comment: @Caballero [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). PHP might have a way to get them from the `exec()` call. I don't know.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I mentioned `exec()` as php function, not Java. Surely, JVM should have some kind of global logging?

Comment: *"php function, not Java"*  My bad.  :P

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in my particular situation in case of exception the output seems to be null, as in: `$result = \exec("java -jar " . $path . " " . $input, $output, $return);` where `$result` is null, `$return` is 1 (or true) and `$output` is an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

here how you can enable logging  ... (notice this is just java logging and the application logging is different from java logging)

- Type

  which java

you get something like this /somewhere/jdk1.7.0_21_linux_x64/bin/java

- Go to the path (exclude the last"java" in the path so it end with bin.
  cd /somewhere/jdk1.7.0_21_linux_x64/bin/
- execute the java control panel this way

./ControlPanel

- You get the screen below (go to the advanced tab) and just enable the logging you like.

[image]

Comment: I have enabled logging like as per your answer, but there is still nothing in `/var/log`. How do I find where the log itself is and whether it's working at all? Also, does this logging cover exceptions?

Comment: according to Oracle, when enabled the log file should be in `~/.java/deployment`, but there is no log file in my case.

Comment: 1. correct, type  env |grep USER_JPI_PROFILE to make sure no one has set it to be another directory instead of ~/.java/deployment. 2. restart your os

Comment: Did all that, still no change. `env | grep USER_JPI_PROFILE` outputs nothing, which I assume means everything is ok.